# System i Navigator stops ASP.NET v4.0 from running in app pool

Tags: .net-4.0, odbc, iis-7.5, db2-400, websphere

I have an intranet page running on IIS 7.5. I need to get System i Navigator installed on that machine for some of the back end services to work. When I install System i Navigator, the ASP.NET v4.0 app pool stops and won't restart. It's driving me insane trying to fix it. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked EventViewer? Is there any logs? I would suspect there is something in their as to why it is stopping instantly.

Comment: I don't know if related to your issue but intalling iSeries access will mess up C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.Config in the DB Providers section - eaves two end tags, </DbProviderFactories>, for the section.  Remove one of the end tags.  I could be way off base if this could cause the issue you have or not.

Comment: It sounds like something was injected to your worker process which cause application pool crashed immediately. Please check event viewer and you should be able to find the crash event. Please post that and we should be able to provide more advice.

Comment: @ScottMildenberger that end tag was the issue. Thank you for the help

Comment: posted as answer if you want to mark as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Installing iSeries access will mess up C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.Config in the DB Providers section - leaves two end tags, for DbProviderFactories, for the section. Remove one of the end tags.